# Web application hosted in OpenLiberty cannot find classes through system class loader

Tags: open-liberty, classloading

I have hosted a web application in open liberty and I am trying to class load some third party java classes which are in a jar. I added the folder as a library which contain the jar file and added that library as a class loader. but i am getting a class not found exception when i try to load it.

**Also when I use URLClassLoader it works perfectly fine. But i want to change the URLClassLoader to System ClassLoader**

My server.xml contains below lines.

```
 <application location="${application.name}"
               type="war"
               id="${application.name}"
               name="${application.name}" context-root="<URL>">
    <classloader apiTypeVisibility="spec, ibm-api, api, stable, third-party" commonLibraryRef="Lib"/>
  </application>

  <library id="Lib" apiTypeVisibility="spec, ibm-api, api, stable, third-party">
    <folder dir="${wlp.install.dir}/../custom-java/" />
  </library>
```

Any help regarding this highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to use the system classloader instead of one that can load libraries defined this way?

Comment: since we can have libraries bundled inside the jar file we need to avoid scenarios like loading the same library twice. if we use the system class loader it will raise an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a jar file, you need to use `<file>` or `<fileset>` instead of `<folder>`.

For a single jar:

```
<library id="Lib" apiTypeVisibility="spec, ibm-api, api, stable, third-party">
  <file name="${wlp.install.dir}/../custom-java/myjar.jar" />
</library>
```

For a directory with multiple jars:

```
<library id="Lib" apiTypeVisibility="spec, ibm-api, api, stable, third-party">
  <fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/../custom-java/" includes="*.jar" scanInterval="5s" />
</library>
```

I believe `<folder>` is only used when you have a folder of files you want to load with `Class.getResource()`, or if you have a directory structure of `.class` files which aren't in a jar.

For more details, see the [Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_sharedlibrary.html)

**Update:** When you've added a library to your application like this, you should be able to access the classes in the library just like you access classes in your application.

For example, these should work:

- `new MyLibraryObject()`
- `Class.forName("com.example.MyLibraryObject")`
- `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass("com.example.MyLibraryObject")`

However, using the *system* classloader specifically still won't work.

In OpenLiberty, the system classloader loads a minimal set of classes. Liberty internals are loaded using OSGi which has its own set of classloaders and application classes are loaded by a special application classloader which can load the application classes, API classes and shared libraries, but doesn't have access to load any liberty internal classes.

Comment: I tried with a fileset and also tried to use .class files instead of .jar. I still get the same ClassNotFoundException. I think problem is not with how i have specified the library. Because it works fine for the URLClassLoader. It only raises the error when I use the System Class loader.

Comment: How are you using the system class loader?

When you add a shared library, you should be able to access the classes in the library in the same way that you access classes in your application.

Comment: Specifically, `new MyLibraryObject()` should work, as should `Class.forName("com.example.MyLibraryObject")`. Actually using the _system_ classloader won't work, it can't see your application classes either. I'll update my answer to include this information.

Comment: `new MyLibraryObject()` cannot be used since i would not know the class name at the compile time.But I will try using `Class.forName("com.example.MyLibraryObject")` and see if that is working.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of fiddling around came up with the answer.
The problem was how I defined the class loader. I changed my class loader to use the Application class loader (this is what mentioned in the Azquelt reply) instead of the the system class loader.

also just adding a library path was enough. no need to specify in the class loader in the server.xml

thank you for your input @Azquelt